# Having trouble getting mypy to recognize that variable implements a protocol

Tags: python, protocols, mypy

The following code generates an error when run with `mypy --strict`

```
from typing import Protocol

class Proto(Protocol):
  id: int
  name: str
  def work(self, hours: float) -> str: ...  

class RoleA:
  def work(self, hours: float) -> str:
    return f"A {hours}"

class RoleB:
  def work(self, hours: float) -> str:
    return f"B {hours}"

class X:
  def __init__(self, id: int, name: str) -> None:
    self.id = id
    self.name = name

class Y(X, RoleA):
  def __init__(self, id: int, name: str) -> None:
    super().__init__(id, name)

class Z(X, RoleB):
  def __init__(self, id: int, name: str) -> None:
    super().__init__(id, name)

def track(items: list[Proto], hours: float) -> None:
  for item in items:
    result = item.work(hours)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  y = Y(id = 4, name = "Jane Doe")
  z = Z(id = 3, name = "Kevin Bacon")
  items =  [y, z]
  track(items, 40)
```

The error is as follows:

> program.py:38: error: Argument 1 to "track" has incompatible type "List[X]"; expected "List[Proto]"

I don't understand why this occurs, as far as I can tell `Y` and `Z` both implement the `Proto` protocol, so why isn't `mypy` able to deduce that they are valid arguments to the `track` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every variable gets a specific type bound to it when it's declared.  For non-generic types with no annotation, it's simply the type of the object on the right side of the assignment, and this is almost always the right thing (unless you plan to reassign it to a different type later, in which case you need to declare it as a union beforehand so that it can accept either type).

When you don't explicitly declare the type parameter for a generic type, like a list or other collection:

```
items = [y, z]
```

mypy makes a best guess at it.  In this case it's `List[X]`, because `X` is the most obvious common type of `y` and `z`.  The vast majority of the time the inferred type is the one you want, but sometimes it's either too broad or too narrow, in which case you can specify one explicitly:

```
items: list[Proto] = [y, z]  # or typing.List[Proto] for python <3.10
```

This will fix the error on your `track` call.

In general I don't think mypy will infer a `Protocol` type as the common type of multiple objects (since a given object might implement any number of protocols), so you'll need to declare it explicitly one way or another.

Comment: It's interesting to think about how mypy could potentially do more detailed inference, e.g. by compiling an intersection of all the protocols implemented by `y` and `z` and including that in the inferred type of `items`.  In practice I think it'd be a bad tradeoff (compared to just explicitly doing the type annotation), because having all that extra type information in every case would make debugging way more difficult across the board.

Comment: Do I have to assign the type upon declaration in this case? Or is there perhaps a way to "trick" `mypy` into inferring the correct type??

Comment: Just assign it when you declare `items`.  There are other ways to do it but they won't make your life easier.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but I think I'd still like to know what those other ways might look like.

Comment: One way is to do `track([y, z], 40)` instead of assigning `items` in the first place.  Works for this snippet, but not in the general case.  Another is to declare a superclass that inherits `X` and `Proto` and have `Y` and `Z` inherit from that, so the inferred type becomes something that conforms to `track`'s parameter.  You're just moving the explicit declaration somewhere else, though, and also then you're not really using protocols any more.